# Find all dir's called "example", set it and its contents writable

Tags: shell, directory, rights, writable

I have a site, with some template directories, there are a few modules, each with their own template dir (So there are N dirs called `templates`).

Each of those dirs has a dir in it, called `translated`. I need a script to set all those dirs and it's contents writable.

I prefer this via a loop so I can echo the result. My shell skills are (still) very minimal, I can't seem to combine them, I can find the dirs from the current working directory, but I can't seem to get it recursive:

```
for f in ./*/translated/
do
    echo $f
done
```

This only finds `./templates/translated/`, but not `./some/dirs/deeper/translated/`

I can use `$f` now for a `chmod a+rw`, but this will only set the contents writable, how do I also get the dir itself? I need new files to be written in it too.

Summery:
1) How do I make it recursive?
2) How do I set the dir itself to `+rw`?

Comment: I rolled back your edit.  Your additional question is significant enough to be posted as a separate question.  When you post a new question, feel free to add a link back to this question if you feel that it is useful as background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool for finding stuff recursively is called `find`.

```
find . -name 'translated' -type d -exec echo chmod -R u+rw {} +
```

Take out the `echo` if you are satisfied with the results.  If your `find` does not support `-exec ... +` then try with `-exec ... \;` instead.

Some shells have a wildcard `**` which will do the same thing, but then your script will be tied to that particular shell.

Comment: Good training-wheels idiom: "echo first and remove the echo if happy with it"

Comment: Not really the "echo each found dir" method I hoped, but this is nice and simple, less code means less room for error :)

Comment: You can put `chmod -v` to see what it's doing, or loop on the output from `find` if you replace the `-exec` with `-print` (or `-print0` if you have GNU `find`; see the manual for the benefits and implications). Quick googling should find you tens of thousands of examples now that you know the basics.